# authorizing wallet

Tags: pda, mainnet, walletprovider

i have an smart contract that want to create pda for it. i did this on devnet and testnet without problem. but on mainnet it response me "403 error" and say "authorize your wallet on node providers".

update soloution:
problem was from rpc node provider. thanks

Comment: Can you provide the source code or link so that I can check it ?
After checking your code, I will place my answer again.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely an issue with your RPC. You should sign up for a free plan on a Private RPC provider (Helius, Triton, Quicknode), 403 is an IP blocking response.